# Julia ERROR: 'Can't Promote to Common Type' for multivariate polynomials in Nemo Library

Tags: julia, polynomials, finite-field

I am new to Julia and have been trying to compute some polynomials using the Nemo library's multivariate polynomials. I have the following code:

```
    R = GF(2); # create finite field
    S, (z, x) = PolynomialRing(R, ["z", "x"]); # Multivariate polynomial

    # polynomial initialisations
    L = x^0; 
    E_L = x^0;
    E = x*0;
    
    a = z;
    w = [1 1 a^3 a^2 a^1 0 0];
    
    n = length(w); #input vector, in terms of a
    j = 1;
    for i = 1:n

        if(w[i] != 0)

            L = L*(1-(a^i)*x); # equation for the locator polynomial
            
            if(i != j)
                E_L = E_L*(1-(a^j)*x);
            end
            j = j + 1;

            E = E + w[i]*(a^i)*E_L; # LINE WITH ERROR 

        end
    end
```

I am not entirely sure why the line with the expression for `E` throws an error.

I have tried a similar thing with the declaration for `L`: `L = L + L*(1-(a^i)*x)` to see whether it was something to do with the addition of two polynomials, however, this works fine. Therefore, I am confused as to why `E`'s expression throws an error.

Any help would greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code runs without error here. Perhaps it is a version issue. Rerun from clean Julia session. It ran for me with Julia 1.8.3 and Nemo 0.35.5. (to check Nemo version, press `]` for Pkg mode and then `status Nemo`

Comment: Thank you for your reply @DanGetz. I just checked and I am currently using Nemo v0.32.3. How can I upgrade an individual package?

Comment: `]` to enter Pkg mode and then `update Nemo` (be sure also to rerun Julia afterwards). If this doesn't work, maybe something is holding it back.